# sendKeys doesn't work in Selenium webdriver

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, ace-editor

First I am trying `sendKeys` at Selenium IDE Like that

Command `waitForElementPresent` Target `css=.ace_text-input` Value=

Command `sendKeys` Target `css=.ace_text-input` Value=`<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>`

Command `click` Target `id=save_changes` Value=

 and it is ok at the Selenium IDE.

But I have problem at `Selenium Webdriver` I am writing test for `PHP` like the following.

`$this->assertTrue($this->isElementPresent("css=.ace_text-input"));`

`$this->sendKeys("css=.ace_text-input", <?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>`

`$this->click("id=save_changes");`

Webdriver never show me an errors but in real `<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>` value never type in my test.So, I want to type `<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>` at my test. And I am testing `Code Editor` name is `ace_editor` and it is just acceptable for `sendKeys` command. So, Everybody answer welcome to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `value()` method, like this:

```
$passwordElement=$this->byCssSelector('input[name="LoginForm\[password\]"]');
$passwordElement->value('123456');
```